# How do I set my Openshift remote Git to be the same as my local branch?

Tags: git, openshift

I did a `git reset --hard HEAD~` and now my local copy is where I want to be, but the remote hosted copy of the app up at Openshift is not.

How do I get the remote copy to now be the same as the local version?

Comment: A brief reply to the "Sanitize HTML"-question you just deleted: IMHO it's not very polite to delete a question when folks (i.e. me) are trying to have a conversation to help you out... Just sayin' ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker... Sorry, but I think some other people just play the down-voting game a bit too much for their own merit.

Comment: The downvotes were because your question was unclear. It was not at all obvious a) what exactly you were asking, and b) what task you were trying to accomplish. I understand that downvotes can be annoying, but don't blame other folk; blame yourself for asking an unclear question.  I was in the process of explaining some things, by the way, in addition to my earlier comment, but then you deleted the question, so well ... you just wasted my time with that entire question :-/

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding...@Carpetsmoker Anyway, you seemed to understand the question quite well ;-)

Comment: Anyway, I'm not too impressed with stackoverflow... I don't agree with the ideology. The system is very restrictive and difficult to make use of. There shouldn't be any such thing as a stupid or bad question. As long as people are using good etiquette and not being abusive they should not have other restrictions as to how they ask, what they ask, how often they add comments or edit they make etc... This system is ridiculous.

Comment: I agree that it's not perfect, but in the end, it *does* work, and also works much better than everything that came before it (e.g. forums, maillists, etc.). Things are the way they are for a reason, and it's very very difficult to always make *everyone* happy :-/

Comment: I've been in different areas of IT since the early 90's, and never seen such a restrictive IT forum or system. I think I'm going to write a better, less restrictive and more user friendly one. This limits free speech... It would be much more educational if it allowed people to chat and had less hoops and restrictions  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really the only person working on that repo, you can force push

```
git push --force openshift master
```

(assuming a remote name '`openshift`' from the comments)

But make sure that you know what history you are losing on the remote side.
If won't be lost (still referenced in the reflog of that remote repo, so if you have access to the server, you will be able to restore it if needed)

If you are not the only one, you will have to communicate that even (`push --force`) to the other users, for them to reset their local clone to the new `origin/master`.